# shutdown cannot be executed by node-red exec node in raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red, privileges, reboot

I am having the following issue:

- I have node-red installed on a raspberry pi (Linux)
- I am running a script where I do the following (myscript.sh - found in /home/pi):

  echo $USER

  echo $UID

I can run that script from bash and node-red with the same result:

```
pi
1000
```

But when I try the shutdown command:

```
shutdown -r now
```

I cannot execute that from node-red but I can execute it without problems from bash, although the same user is there (pi).

Is there an explanation for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with using

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

You are running node-red as a regular user, not as a superuser. Meanwhile, bash is always run as superuser.